# How to Know the MIME type of file manually? in my case type is showing "FILE" and don't have extension

Tags: java, mime

Need to know the MIME Types of file without program
file name don't have any extension

Comment: You should add at least a code example of what you have tried. And of course add tags for your programming language.

Comment: can't we find without programming language ? if No then i will prefer JAVA

Comment: Even if it did have an extension, that would not tell you, because each extension could correspond to multiple types.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find it out using plain Java from an `InputStream`.

```
String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
```

Or you just check out the source code from `guessContentTypeFromStream` and open your file in an Editor and compare the hex values yourself.